What plan has Trump proposed to mitigate the predicted inflationary effect of tariffs?
It is widely believed by economists that tariffs on imports to the USA will result in higher prices for consumers. See, for example, this survey of 43 American academic economists in which the statement,

Imposing tariffs results in a substantial portion of the tariffs being borne by consumers of the country that enacts the tariffs, through price increases.

was agreed or strongly agreed with by 95% of participants.
Sometimes, tariffs could be beneficial in the sense that the tariff-imposer country will experience growth in a strategically important sector, say, microprocessors, defense products, aircraft manufacturing, etc.
However, Trump is imposing blanket tariffs on a wide range of goods from China, Mexico, and Canada.

From clothes to electronics, here's all the items that are going to cost more after Donald Trump's proposed tariffs

On top of that, there will be counter tariffs from the opposite countries on various products that they deem will push the USA into an artificial crisis.

Mexico suggests it would impose its own tariffs to retaliate against any Trump tariffs

China Has a New Playbook to Counter Trump: ‘Supply Chain Warfare’


Has trump articulated any plan for the inflation that the tariffs are anticipated to cause, and if so what is it?

Technically the demand isn't higher, it remains the same. And supply isn't less, rather the price demanded for the supply is higher. But the general thrust of your argument, that tariffs will lead to higher prices, is undoubtedly correct.

Closing-wise, surely it should be reasonable enough to ask what Trump's policy plans are in this regards.  After all, most economists don't think the tariffs are going to be beneficial, so how does he intend to avoid the drawbacks?  Normal politicians do outline what they intend to do.

I think the issue is that people are considering the tariffs in isolation. Trump isn't raising tariffs just to generate revenue or protect a local industry, he's using them as a lever in other negotiations, for example demanding immigration border controls from Mexico.

It will be interesting to see how this question age. Tariffs are usually a left-wing tool that is very common in Europe etc. For history this question is asked at a time where it now confuses some that a right-leaning president wants to use this tool.

@ThomasKoelle The left-right issue is more confused than that: in the UK, repeal of the Corn Laws in the 19th century came from progressives trying to reduce the price of bread, and the first ever Labour government came to power in 1924 precisely because the Conservatives fought the previous election saying they wanted to increase tariffs and lost.

Your understanding of supply-demand is quite sketchy. You should go back to the basics: draw supply and demand curves and shift them graphically. You should also get into the habit of saying "the demand curve shifts at every price" and "the equilibrium moves along the demand curve as the supply curve shifts" rather than "there is higher demand", which is ambiguous and, consequently, could be just as true as false.

To answer your question, something like this will happen: The stock market will crash, the U.S. will enter a recession, and the downward pressure on prices caused by the recession will offset the upward prices caused by tariffs. In the end, Trump will blame the recession on Mexico/China/France (one of them or possibly all three) and claim he was right all along and half of America will believe him.

@ThomasKoelle - Trump isn't using it as a tariff, he's using it as a weapon. He's going to force America's key market partners to cooperate on other issues like dumping and immigration in return for a relaxation of tariff controls.

Tariffs are only inflationary if people don't change their purchase habits as a result of the tariffs.

I am shocked you think Trump actually has a plan beyond Step 1 (Raise tariff fees) Step 2 (raise them more if expected result not achieved). He's not a chess player, thinking a dozen steps ahead. I am pretty sure he will call the inflationary effect "fake news".

@Kyralessa Even if they do there is no reason to assume that domestic producing of alternative products would be equally cost-effective. One could still end up with less supply and even more the wrong kind of supply. (Look no cool TV but lots of ketchup bottles, yeah.)

If tariffs are equivalent to a tax on goods, then just lowering taxes somewhere else (federal income taxes) partially fixes the problem on the domestic side.  He has said he wants to further lower domestic income/corporate taxes (though he as not said that is was explicitly for this purpose).  Fixing any retaliation on the foreign side is another matter.

I am starting to believe that these questions want answers which would show that Trump's policies are bad...

@RootGroves Almost like we have four years of proof already.

@suchiuomizu the only reason there werent any MORE jobs during Trump's first term was because the deep state and the masons(and especially a specific untold person('good' old Georgie)) were antagonising Trump and his policies.

The answer from his campaign, rather than Trump himself is something like

“In his first term, President Trump instituted tariffs against China that created jobs, spurred investment and resulted in no inflation,’’ Anna Kelly, a spokeswoman for the Republican National Committee, has said.

Of course, critics say that what he's proposing now is much more, e.g.

“The Trump tariffs in 2018-19 didn’t have as large an impact as the tariffs were only just over $300 billion in mostly Chinese imports,’’ he said. “The former president is now talking about tariffs on over $3 trillion in imported goods across all countries.’’

Trump himself answered a question about food prices being too high by saying that there should be higher tariffs

Asked how he would lower grocery prices — a particular irritant to many Americans — Trump has said the nation should limit the importation of food because America’s farmers are “being decimated’’ by foreign competition.

And

Trump insists that the cost of taxing imported goods is absorbed by the foreign countries that produce those goods.

Make of this what you will. Some commenters have said that he simply relied on the economic ineptitude of his voters to believe that he can achieve both low inflation and high tariffs.

“That this policy stance is inflationary is very difficult for most voters to grasp, especially when they are being told the opposite.’’


Alas I can't find a direct quote from him in this election cycle saying that tariffs are paid by foreign countries, but he's definitely made that claim around 2019, with respect to China. It apparently didn't matter (to Trump) that he was contradicting what some of this official economic advisers like Larry Kudlow were publicly saying about this.
He's also said it in the debate with Biden in 2020.

“China” is “paying billions and billions of dollars” on U.S. tariffs, President Trump said in his debate with Joe Biden on October 22 [2020]. “And you know who got the money? Our farmers. Our great farmers.”

So that was 'Trumponomics' then.
TBF, his new plan sounds more ambitious:

Trump’s stated plan to lower inflation has five key pillars: ditch restrictions on domestic energy production, cut “wasteful” government spending, reduce regulations, crack down on immigration and “restore peace” worldwide.

Although many economists (and not just in the US context) argue that (illegal) immigrants drive prices down, not up, by working for less,

Republicans argue that imposing tighter border restrictions and conducting widespread deportations will help “reverse” policies under Biden that they claim have driven up housing, education and healthcare costs.

If I'm to slightly joke about this: Trump is planning to deport inflation.
And he says that massive oil drilling will even bring grocery food prices down:

Speaking in front of a table of packaged foods, Trump used an August press conference to draw attention to food inflation during his campaign for president. “Grocery prices have skyrocketed,” he said.
“When I win, I will immediately bring prices down, starting on day one,” Trump continued. “We will drill, baby, drill,” he said, referring to increasing domestic oil production. “That’s going to bring down prices of everything.”

This despite the fact that around 40% of US farm workers are illegal immigrants, whom he says he plans to quickly deport.

BTW, his plan will probably plunge Mexico into a recession, increasing emigration pressures there. https://www.latimes.com/world-nation/story/2024-10-27/mexico-trump-tariff-threat-recession-economy-immigration So, it's not just inflation that's not aligned with his tariff plans.

Farming is a huge US export although it has an overall deficit.  Didn't the farmers get screwed last time Trump was at the helm of a China trade war?  His best bet is that the other countries fold, but if they don't...

I think I figured out who he's going to blame for inflation. It will probably be the oil companies who don't see too excited about drilling him out of tariffs-induced inflation https://www.reuters.com/markets/commodities/us-oil-producers-unlikely-shift-drill-baby-drill-mode-says-exxon-executive-2024-11-26/ https://theweek.com/business/economy/big-oil-drill-trump-production-output-energy-fracking-gas Maybe he'll nationalize them ;-P

Immigration in context of a housing shortage may drive rents up.  Are rents included in inflation calculations?

China was accused of dumping some products (e.g. steel) with subsidised low prices in the US. So to that extent, it might pay tariffs on goods along with existing subsidies. But on other goods, particularly those with less connection the the Chinese state or less economic significance, it's unlikely to pay subsidies.

As far as I can tell, Trump doesn't think it will end in inflation. Instead he thinks the other countries will bow to his will to not lose access to the huge US market. See, if the ultimate loser from tariffs really are US consumers, then other countries wouldn't mind that much, it's none of their business and it's the US that suffers anyway. But after threatening tariffs on China/Mexico/Canada, all three countries are voicing displeasure and considering retaliation. Therefore, one can conclude that these tariffs hurt them too.
Presumably, Trump is aware that tariffs will hurt the US, but as long as the other country suffers more, then they will fold first (by e.g. stopping the flow of immigrants into the country). He did say during his first presidency that the US's large trade deficit meant that there are more things that he can impose tariffs on than other countries can retaliate on. And as long as the other country folds first, then it's a win for the US.

What is Trump's plan for the source of imports that the USA cannot replace, e.g., Canadian oil, Mexican avocado, Chinese consumer electronics, etc.?

Still want to sell these things in the US? Move your plants here and hire a bunch of US workers, or pay the tariffs.
How effective the above plan is, is another matter.

I think this answer, which has zero actual quotes from Trump is 'sanewashing' him. Trump for instance answered with a straight face a Q about higher food prices by saying that there should be higher tariffs on imported food because American farmers are being 'decimated'. That doesn't read like he wants that as a temporary measure. https://news.wttw.com/2024/10/15/donald-trump-s-economic-plans-would-worsen-inflation-mainstream-economists-say Yeah, some of his tariffs may be that way, but not all. And he just plain ignores inflation in relation to some other objectives.

The general economic theory says that a tariff will hurt both sides, the exporter because they can sell less and the importer because they will suffer higher prices. The other countries don't need to 'fold', even if only the US imposes tariffs and there is no retaliation, it will still hurt both the US and the countries that export to the US.

@quarague yes, but when you think your country has a higher "suffer threshold" than the other country, then you might still bet that they will fold before you do.

The suffering may not be distributed equally but there is no folding. Trump introduces tariffs, everyone suffers economically, some more than others. Even if say Mexico suffers a lot more than the US, there is still only the US tariff in play in this scenario, Mexico can't fold anything, the just suffer from Trumps tariff. The folding only applies to the question on whether they retaliate or not but even if they don't, there is still economic loss on both sides.

@quarague What do you mean Mexico can't fold anything? They can, e.g., agree to raise their de minimis exemption thresholds for the application of taxes and customs duties, which is one of many things they agreed to in 2018 in NAFTA 2.0.

@Allure That would be using the tariff (that hurts both sides) as a threat to get Mexico to pay some kind of tribute that is independent of the tariff. Classic blackmail with the special feature that the bully also hurts himself. I wouldn't call that folding but that may be a language issue.

@quarague "Folding" is a relatively gentle word to use; some others use 'coercion'.

"Move your plants here " - that's going to take longer than Trump's term for many businesses.  Will those tariffs still be in place when the companies say "we're building a plant it's not ready yet", so the tariffs are lowered until Trump's term ends, and the plants stop getting built.

@Neil Maybe? Trump's original China tariffs didn't get repealed by Biden.

I think the description of the effects of tariffs is not quite right.
Say a Chinese company can build a product and put it on a shelf in a US store for $80, then we add $10 for the manufacturer’s and $10 for the stores profit, so a US resident buys it for $100.
35% tariff on the $90, plus the seller wanting the same 10% profit, means the same product can be purchased for $135.
The first effect is fewer sales at a higher price. The manufacturer can’t reduce their profits enough to keep the price at $100. A US company who sold the same product for $110 and has no capacity to build more can raise their prices to $120 or $130. If they can increase capacity, then they will do that and keep selling for $110. Anyway, US manufacturers can win, consumers will lose.
The Chinese manufacturer will see revenue dropping in the USA. On the other hand, they have spare capacity to sell more in Europe. They can slightly reduce EU prices, and US manufacturers will be uncompetitive in Europe.
For products without spare capacity in the USA, US manufacturers will gain less and consumers will lose more.

And it's even more difficult. Other countries could retaliate, consumers could lose confidence, imported goods could only be used for further production. But that wasn't the question, the question was only if there is a plan proposed to mitigate some effects. Has there been?


When there will be pressure on the wallets, the people of the tariff-imposer country will lose their purchasing power.

The simple fault is this: you're not accounting for the increased employment of the domestic workforce as import substitution occurs, the increased wages they can command, and the increased development of the working class (such as the can-do and know-how they acquire from increased and better work activity and better living standards).
The explicit intention of Trump's policy is import substitution, and it broadly follows the logic of mercantilism: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mercantilism
In the event the import substitution does not occur - which for an economy with the level of development the US has, can only be because the tariffs are not sufficiently penal upon importers - then they simply revert to acting as an additional sales tax which delivers surplus public funds. The state can respond to this surplus either by cutting other taxes, or by spending on public works, so at an overall level it does not destroy spending power - it reallocates spending power (from citizen to state) or redistributes the burden of taxation (onto those gorging on imports, and from wherever the politician chooses to cut taxes).
Free market liberals hate mercantilism because it strengthens the working class, eroding the ability of liberals to exploit them.
It also either leads to the growth of democracy and state management of the economy (as you see post-WW2) or, unmanaged by democratic mechanisms and with international trade ungoverned, it leads to total war (as you see pre-WW2).
China, practically speaking, runs a mercantilist economy. It coexisted with Western liberalism and their policy of free markets because China benefits from a willingness of the Chinese people to accept high rates of foreign exploitation, in exchange for retrieving know-how and plant machinery from the Western economy. The reason it values these things is because it subscribes to the labour theory of value, in which your economic and military strength originates from your successful organisation and reproduction of a productive working class.
This different valuation of worker capability, and the asymmetry of current possession of that know-how and capital machinery, is basically what acts for China as a "non-tariff barrier" ensuring that it receives work from the West whilst having none taken, without overt tariff measures being necessary to maintain the one-way movement.
Although celebrated later by Marx and other political-economic thinkers, it was classical liberal Adam Smith who first articulated the labour theory of value.
Western liberals hate workers with a passion, whilst celebrating the parasitic rent-seeker and the middle-man, and that is how China has been able to bribe them with profits to ensure China was the beneficiary of Western liberal attacks on its own working class from the 1970s onwards.

@Hobbamok, oh I'm accustomed to it! The silent downvotes show I've hit them where it hurts.
