Have import tariffs ever been good for an economy historically?
How would an import tax affect an economy as a whole?
A. Does it not stimulate the buying of domestic products and therefore put money in the hands of domestic business owners within?
B. Do domestic business lose out even though this reduces the competition from foreign competitors?
C. How would consumers and Business owners fare in comparison? Are workers the most hurt due to this?
I am by no means an economics or politics major, but even from similar questions, the resounding answer was historically "no".
Are Tariffs rather some form of punishment? And if so, why do they not work as intended?
Administrations who push Tariffs must have a strategy in hand.
A quote for some reference from Ferris Bueller's Day Off (1986) where an economics professor discusses historically how tariffs have never worked. (based on true acts of the US government):

Economics Teacher : In 1930, the Republican-controlled House of Representatives, in an effort to alleviate the effects of the... Anyone? Anyone?... the Great Depression, passed the... Anyone? Anyone? The tariff bill? The Hawley-Smoot Tariff Act? Which, anyone? Raised or lowered?... raised tariffs, in an effort to collect more revenue for the federal government. Did it work? Anyone? Anyone know the effects? It did not work, and the United States sank deeper into the Great Depression. Today we have a similar debate over this. Anyone know what this is? Class? Anyone? Anyone? Anyone seen this before? The Laffer Curve. Anyone know what this says? It says that at this point on the revenue curve, you will get exactly the same amount of revenue as at this point. This is very controversial. Does anyone know what Vice President Bush called this in 1980? Anyone? Something-d-o-o economics. "Voodoo" economics.

I'm just trying to understand if there is some reason people keep doing Tariffs as opposed to some other form of intimidation or political instigation?

You could look into Colbert in France.  17th century.  It did work, mostly.  However, a 17th century economy isn't a 21st century one. Welcome and an upvote, but if you have historical questions, please ask @ https://history.stackexchange.com so voting to close.

Hi, and thank you, I was looking into asking at the economics stack exchange, However politically speaking they are used more as a tool of policy than for actual economic growth? At least in the last 20 years or so. The extreme is blocking imports while the other end is open trade.
Edit: I can go ask that there though, just let me know. I have a hard time differentiating history from policy so I appreciate your guidance.

I don't know exactly how they operate.  You could always ask there and put in underneath as a comment that you would understand if they'd migrate to SE.History if it doesn't fit their scope.  SE.History itself tends to sometimes get weird on questions like "has X happened before?".  I know, I know, complicated.

Haha thanks, I'll give it a try and you guys can go ahead and close the question.

Well, let's see what others think.  The Trump tariffs do look like a train wreck in the making, but they haven't happened yet either, so the reception re. questions about them can go either way.

That's what I've been wondering, and also retaliation tariffs now. As you stated, historically it can go either way, there should be some fundamentally overlap in all the different tariffs people observed and how different parts of the economies overlap, but I'm thinking of this too rigidly scientific. The 17th century is different from the 21st century certainly, maybe import taxes have changed with it and the way they are looked. A conjecture.

Let us continue this discussion in chat.

Colbert's shining moment, thought to every wee French schoolchild, was how he bravely stopped the French from importing china (teacups) from Italy and launched a domestic replacement industry.  Mmmmm, OK, but the state stepping and successfully launching one hitherto untried commercial enterprise in the Late Renaissance isn't quite the same thing as a country hitting homeruns each time in an already competitive advanced economy.

https://latinaer.springeropen.com/articles/10.1007/s40503-017-0050-9

"...if there is some reason people keep doing Tariffs..." Typically unfair practices (state subsidies, selling under production prices (dumping), forced labor, ...) are mentioned as reason to introduce tariffs. See the WTO rulesbooks.

You don't have to keep going back to the 17th century. In the 19th century, the US did not have income taxes so almost the entirety of government revenue was tariffs. If you want a real example of how they are implemented and why they were in place for so long, look at US history.

Both on politics SE and on econ SE there are several closely related questions on tariffs (for example https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/89966/trumps-tariff-plan/ or https://economics.stackexchange.com/questions/59496/on-the-love-for-tariffs-what-are-the-benefits-of-tariffs-for-a-nations-economy/). Please check these and see whether they answer your question. VTC as duplicate.

This question is similar to: Trump's tariff plan. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

An important consideration is that of tariffs not just as an economical tool but also as a means of taxation. In some cases (early USA come to mind), tariffs would have been a way of taxation independent from other actors (states in the USA, nobility in feudal and modern Europe).

Speaking from an economic POV, all business costs get pushed to the consumer buying products, including tariffs. And the past couple of years have shown businesses doubling or tripling (at least) their increased costs due to inflation, so the same thing is likely going to happen here. And the economy is based on what consumers can afford, so if the consumers can afford less because of higher prices, they are going to end up dragging down the economy with them. Trumps China Trade War tariffs demonstrate this. https://heinonline.org/HOL/LandingPage?handle=hein.journals/wmaybur12&div=13&id=&page=

Sometimes tariffs have purposes which are not purely financial. E.g many wealthy countries have high import taxes on agricultural products in order to insulate their domestic farming industry from lower-cost competitors. Politicians and voters in those countries are well aware that this results in higher food prices, but accept this, because having a viable farming industry is seen as a good thing in itself (because farmers are seen as "stewards of the countryside" etc, or for food security reasons in the event of war, etc.) Switzerland is a well-known example.

@DavidLoeffler that makes a lot of sense actually, depending on the industry of course, and if countries move away from free trade

@DavidLoeffler But that's not what the question is asking. It's asking for a positive effect on economy. Aside from food security, Swiss farmers would probably be more efficient as bankers or something else, the overall economy would be better off and Swiss farming subsidies or tariffs would not be an example for this question.

My comment doesn't answer the precise question asked in the headline of this post; but the OP's question text asks more generally why tariffs might be beneficial – writing "Administrations who push Tariffs must have a strategy in hand" and "I'm just trying to understand if there is some reason people keep doing Tariffs as opposed to some other form of intimidation or political instigation".

The fundamental problem with the question is that this idea of "good for an/the economy" is a deceptively simple phrase in that it sounds like it's straightforward, but very much isn't.
The problem is that it makes it sound as if "the economy" is a team of homogeneous actors who simultaneously benefit or suffer from a good or bad economy.
However, "the economy" is not one team, but the economy is messy interactions between lots of agents and groups of agents who compete and/or cooperate, for, with and against each other in a multitude of different social, political and economic games.
So, whatever economic idea you might have, it will almost always be good for some and bad for others. And even the idea of a "net positive/negative" is controversial because people are not a collective being, but ultimately individuals, so, for those who lose, it's a net negative, and, for those who win, it's a net positive regardless of what the total/average/media/etc. is doing.
Like, what's the value of a growing GDP of the Chinese economy if you are an Uighur working in a slave-labor camp? So, for a start, you'd need to define what it is that you mean by "good for an economy".
Like, take the example from the question: tariffs.
Now a tariff is something like an import tax, so if you import a good or service from a foreign country, you pay an additional X% in tax. Which in turn means that local goods become cheaper in comparison or that local producers could also raise their prices and grow their profit margin (thanks Joe W for mentioning). However, there are multiple ways in which the various actors can respond to that:

For example, the importer can decide to increase the price of the product by the same amount that they pay more, thus making the customers pay more.

They can share the increase between the customers and themselves, making both suffer from it, albeit less individually than before.

They can decide to keep the prices stable and instead shrink their profit margin by that amount (if the profit margin is large enough) or take a loss and hope that this policy will fade soon.

Also, the exporter could react and lower the prices to keep the effective price for the importer stable by lowering their own profit margins.


In those cases you'd have a redistribution of wealth in the direction of the government, who gets the extra taxes, that is either paid for by the consumers, the importers or the exporters. Now a government might sell it as the exporters paying it, but it's very likely that also or exclusively importers and customers are going to pay for it.

Or it's possible that the importers take in products at a reduced price from their suppliers and sell them higher to the consumers because they expect a raise through the tariffs where the exports subsidize the imports, and the government creates a higher demand for those particular products over domestic ones.

Or the importers might dodge the tariffs entirely by moving their production to the tariff-imposing country, which can be a positive (jobs and tax revenue) or a negative (making use of local subsidizes while realizing profits in a tax haven).

Or the exporting country might react with tariffs of their own, which levels the prices of competitors but means importers and/or consumers still pay more—or that the trade volume in general is decreased, which might hurt countries more or less depending on how dependent they were on imports or exports.

Also, when it comes to importing not products but raw materials, this can have ripple effects on a huge variety of other industries. Like, if the supply chains are cut off, that can bring entire economies to a grinding halt, and whenever you'll have to find a drop-in replacement FAST, you'll usually pay a premium for that. So, if the state has to step in and help companies struggling from the effect of the tariffs, that extra tax cash can be gone fast.


So, already, in theory that can have a huge array of possible outcomes that can be both positive, negative and both, the effects of which can be felt differently by different actors.
So, wielding these weapons is kind of a double-edged sword as a lot of things can happen that you didn't intend or anticipate.
Also, with regards to whether they work, that's also a matter of time-scale. Like, usually you can only tell in hindsight and in the long term, but, by their nature, their biggest effect is already imposed on shorter time scales, so planning that is a mixed bag.
The thing is, while lots of people like to speak about a "free market" and whatnot, with respect to economic players, those people usually don't want to "play the game" but "win it"—that is, to be the monopoly producers (even if it is just in a niche), where they can manipulate the market and make steady profits on their sales.
So the classic strategy is to reduce prices, make your competitors drop out, buy them or render them dysfunctional and then use your dominant position to increase the prices to recover the loss and make a profit. Now, in theory, the increasing prices would then enable new competitors to make a profit and expand so that, long term, things get back to normal over time.
However, depending on the nature of the industry, that can take quite some time. Like, idk, if you have a service industry, and you make the competitors drop out, and all they need is a regular office or even just a computer and a Starbucks working remote, then making them drop out will not keep them out for long, but if you have an industrial company with a large supply chain, then building new plants, hiring professionals and building know-how, supply chains and distribution networks can be costly and time-intensive, so building and rebuilding them can take significantly longer—just to get back to zero.
So tariffs are usually more of a defensive strategy. So let's say a country/company sells products way below the market price/quality ratio so that local domestic competitors either can't compete at all or only at the price of doing so at a loss. Then it can make sense to artificially raise the price of the exporters' products so that the prices on your local market stay stable, and your local companies can survive.
If that was a short-term move by that other country/company, then over time they will make ever higher losses and eventually give up. Whereas, if that is the effect of actually lowering production costs, they can keep up with that without making any losses. Then this mainly means that your consumers and those who have that product in their supply chain will pay more than what's customary on the global market, which will result in a decrease of trade—not just imports, but also exports—and over time probably illegal and non-business imports will subvert the tariffs' effectiveness as products will enter your market at lower prices, which your local economy can't compete with, one way or another.
So tariffs and subsidies can make sense if you want to grow or protect a domestic industry from external volatility over a short period of time before they can stand on their own (again) or the other way around if you want to disrupt a market short term to take advantage of a lack of protection against those things. But as a long-term strategy or an all-purpose super weapon, they aren't necessarily the best idea especially as all of these things can also backfire massively.
Edit: Also ghellquist and Tiercelet mention examples in the comment, but might be better suited as their own answers.

This is a nice overview of what can go right or wrong but what about concrete examples in history? Are there examples where for some definition of good (average wealth increased, many people profiting) tariffs actually did good?

@NoDataDumpNoContribution I believe the so called Asian Tiger economies can be an example. During a period they used a number of institutions including tariiffs to kick-start their economy. The "standard" recipe for development generally has four components: protect and promote domestic industry and make sure there is a local market for the goods, spend on infrastructure, spend on eduction and make sure capital markets and currency are stable. These four factors may work for a while, but needs to be modified over time.

Also note that if the government is collecting X amount of money in tariffs, then in theory, they can just reduce income taxes by X amount and have the same revenue.  In that case consumers on average don't' wind up paying more, but who winds up paying may change.  The tax brackets likely get flattened in this case.  But at the same time, if you do get local jobs out of it then it could be a net gain for the economy.

"So, it tariffs and subsidies can make sense if you want to grow or protect a domestic industry from external volatility".  This is very true with respect to the relationship between the US and foreign electronic components suppliers.  Nearly all of our advanced electronics, including ones for military purposes, likely rely on lots of parts from China, Taiwan, Philippines, etc.  There are national security reasons to want to bring microchip and electronics component manufacturing back to the US, even if it has some negative effect on GDP.

IF you want to get really concrete, this is essentially the strategy followed by South Korea during the post-Korean-War era, particularly under Park Chung Hee. The strategy consisted of using tariffs, plus outright import restrictions (and convenient foreign aid) to run government-directed import-replacement industrialization while suppressing internal consumption and becoming a net exporter of increasingly high value-add goods. This worked, largely because the US was willing to tolerate the measures if they were tied to staunch anti-communism.

This is a great answer but I feel that it is lacking in a key possible outcome. It is also possible that domestic producers can also increase prices while staying below the increase from tariffs which just means an overall price increase for consumers and more profits for the domestic producers.

The main problem with a lot of these discussions is that people over-analyze a tariff's domestic direct effect, in isolation.  That has a mixed bag, somewhat negative, effect by traditional economics analysis (refer for example to the SE.Economics question linked to in a comment).
The risk when imposing tariffs unilaterally, and rather arbitrarily, is that, historically, those types of moves do not go unchallenged and trade wars tend to ensue.
So, it is incorrect to reason solely in terms of "tariffs action X gives result A".  It's also "tariffs X will trigger counter tariffs Y giving results A and B".
For example, in Trump's previous trade spats with China, relatively limited by comparison to what he has been campaigning on this time, US soy farmers were seriously hurt in their China exports.
If Europe is also included, it certainly will be hurt, but it will find ways to get back at the US.
Besides the typical kind of tariff retaliation, China also has the card to play to limit its exports of stuff where it is dominant in critical supply chains, such as rare earths.
In this type of situation, most negative issues are not directly due to tariffs - unlike what we see when nations practice long term autarky policies.  They are due to the spread of retaliatory trade wars.
Last, in the case of Canada and Mexico, given the trade agreements in place - agreed to during Trump 1 - this is further eroding the "rule of law" in trade relations and the US's reputation as a good faith actor.
p.s. Now, it is possible this is just a negotiating gambit by Trump, and crass though those are, sometimes they have beneficial effects (see the 2% NATO spending goal) and that the actual tariffs are going to be much more limited.  That is a possibility, and perhaps even a strong one.  But this answer is only addressing the risks of actual tariff imposition.

This answer comments on why it might not be such a good idea especially when including retaliatory actions, but that's not what the question was asking. It asked if there were instances where the tariffs (and all their implications) resulted in a positive outcome on the economy. Were there such cases? Maybe not in the US even.

"refer for example to the SE.Economics answer linked to in a comment" To ease reading, please add the link to the comment and/or the answer, in this answer.


A. Does it not stimulate the buying of domestic products and therefore put money in the hands of domestic business owners within?

Analyzing economics by simply looking at the flow of "money", rather than the underlying wealth effects, is a simplistic viewpoint. Businesses throughout the supply chain are going to be getting "more money", but most of them are also going to have more expenses.

B. Do domestic business lose out even though this reduces the competition from foreign competitors?

Businesses that have a natural advantage, or that have invested, in something targeted by tariffs can benefit. But simply being in an industry with tariffs doesn't mean that you'll benefit, if you don't have an advantage that can't be competed away. For instance, if you have an iron mine, and there are steel tariffs, then competitors can't just make new iron mines pop out of nowhere, so you'll probably benefit. If you own a dairy farm and there are dairy tariffs, on the other hand, most of your benefits are going to be competed away by other people realizing that there's now money to be made, and getting into the dairy business.

C. How would consumers and Business owners fare in comparison?

Consumers would almost universally be hurt. Business owners are both producers and consumers, so the effects on them would be mixed and depend on where they sit in supply chain. There's also the fact that people would have less disposable income. and so buy less stuff, but if you sell an inferior good (this term has a specific economic definition) then you may benefit.

Are workers the most hurt due to this?

This phrasing can be misleading, because people don't exist solely as "workers". They're working to make money, and they use that money to buy stuff, so they're consumers as well. Generally speaking, tariffs tend to cause the nominal wages of workers to, on average, go up. However, tariffs are also increasing the costs of goods, so the overall amount that the wages can buy, i.e. the real wages, is going down.
Protectionist policies are often sold as "creating jobs", and if having people work more is a terminal goal for you, then tariffs are indeed a good idea. If, however, employment is not a goal in and of itself, but a means towards the goal of being able to afford things, then it's not such a good idea. Yeah, there's going to be more jobs, but people are going to need more jobs to afford the higher prices. If a bunch of people have to take a second job to make ends meet, then yes, there are "more jobs", but is that a good thing?

Administrations who push Tariffs must have a strategy in hand.

Trump's actions  can't analyzed from an economic strategy standpoint. Economics assumes rational actors, and Trump is driven by psychological factors, and his interests are not the nation's interests.

Are Tariffs rather some form of punishment? And if so, why do they not work as intended?

There's probably some extent of people feeling that buying from foreign suppliers is "disloyal" and so there some punitive intent behind them. And in that, they are effective, in that they deter foreign purchases, and cause harm to people who make foreign purchases. There are also retaliatory tariffs, that are intended to punish other countries for their tariffs, and those are somewhat effective.

and his interests are not the nation's interests => to be fair, it’s rare for politicians to be able to implement policies that benefit the nation as a whole. Just look at German voters who picked Russian gas over a tiny risk of a nuclear meltdown.

Lets forget about tariffs (!) and think in terms of imports that are expensive compared to imports that are cheap. Lets just assume that one country we are buying from is selling something at high price and another country we are buying from is selling something at low price.
This simplification works because putting tariffs increase price of imported items (and putting subsidies reduces price of imported items). Its not necessary that end-consumer suffer (or benefit) from the tariffs (or subsidies). It may be the middle-men - the traders - that absorbs the difference.
So, is it good to buy from a country thats selling something cheap. The knee-jerk reaction would be yes but it would miss some important considerations.
First, would you really want to depend on a foreign country you have no control on for the thing you are importing. Importing something at cheaper price than you can produce in your country will eventually kill your own industry. Is that a path you should follow?
It cannot be denied that cheaper foreign goods imported in large enough quantity will eventually kill local industry. No escape from that. Do you want to kill your local industry?
Again the answer is not a clear yes or no. It depends. It do not depend on monetary benefit. It depends on the power situation. Simply, is the other country depending enough on you to not in future cut the supplies or increase price drastically?
Yes, its beneficial for all parties to produce only what they are good in producing, and buy the rest from the others. Its like why an individual choose a profession and not for example grow his own crops and weave his own clothes. Thats how individuals and societies prosper, through trade.
The thing that a society and an individual both have to be careful about is to not be dependent on something that can be easily taken away. For example, if you are living on social security or any kind of govt help and your country is facing an invasion or a serious economic crisis then you better start developing some skills and start doing some work. The govt's income support can end at any time.
If you are stuck in a profession thats quickly outdating then you are in trouble. What you are selling may not have a market in near future while what you need to buy (food etc) have to be bought because you dont have your own farm.
In case of USA the dependence is high. Its reflective in severe trade imbalance. World is not buying enough from USA to pay for what USA is buying from world. Its like you, an individual, start living on credit. Your income is less than your expenses and so your debt accumulate. Soon nobody will be selling you anything because of your inability to pay the debt - the actual debt, not the interest on it. Nobody will be accepting your credit card. What will you do then?
Now, if its luxury or even comfort goods you can survive without its not very bad. For a country its worse because countries have to maintain armies too. If any of the essential weapons or ammunition production depends on a material whose supply can be cut off any time then you are basically set up for extreme give aways of your assets, economically or militarily.
